# Superposition of bodies in space.

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a complex solid in space composed of three solids. I need a parametric equation for the entire body. I'm guessing that having an equation for each solid and applying the superposition principle I'll be able to get the equation. Is this correct? If so, how?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This question is likely to be closed as too vague. What is "superposition"? What does "pull out an equation" mean? If you can edit the question to provide more specific information perhaps we can help. (Don't try to clarify in comments. Edit the question.)

Comment: Probably this question is more suited to https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you @EthanBolker for your input.